# Include value from list in PyQGIS selectByExpression command

Tags: pyqgis

I've been going through the [cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#selecting-features) to try to find a way to include a value from a list in a selection command and can't figure it out.

```
roadlist=[]
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    if feature['RoadMntnc'] not in roadlist:
        roadlist.append(feature['RoadMntnc'])

for road in roadlist:
    print (road)
    layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= road', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
    selection=layer.selectedFeatures()
    for feature in selection:
        print (feature['chainage'])
```

How should the following line be structured to include the value for road from roadlist?

```
layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= road', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```

If I put in the name of a road as `layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= \'Main_Rd\'', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)` it works fine but I need the iterative value from roadlist.

Comment: Try this `layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= \'{0}\''.format(road), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)`

Comment: Works well -thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) in order to loop on each road type. Therefore, change the following line

```
layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= road', QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```

to

```
layer.selectByExpression('"RoadMntnc"= \'{0}\''.format(road), QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
```